# How to make dropdown in navbar appear with keyboard access key?

Tags: html, css

I set my `accesskey` of the drop-down menu to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>; my div tags are as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn" accesskey="L"> .... </a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

  <a href={option 1}>....</a>
  <a href={option 2}>....</a>
```

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> highlights the drop-down tab, but doesn't open it up. What should I do to make the keyboard shortcut also open up the drop-down menu?

Comment: maybe that way you have just the focus and after that you have to use the cursor keys to open up the dropdown options? in terms of accessibility it's like saying that you get the focus on a text input and after that your input media is bound to that control, after then you need to send him the input to use it. Maybe I went too far with words. Any way your question your rules. There are surely options to get where you are aiming.

Comment: With regards to "making [*the HTML] show up*", please see the "[Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)" page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a[accesskey]` is missing either an `href` or `tabindex` attribute to be focusable.

examples

```css
[accesskey]:focus + div  {border:solid;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn" accesskey="L" href="#nowhere"> .... </a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <a href={option 1}>....</a>
    <a href={option 2}>....</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn" accesskey="O" tabindex="0"> .... </a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <a href={option 1}>....</a>
    <a href={option 2}>....</a>
  </div>
</div>
```